# What is the term for someone who hates themselves on the behalf of others?

Tags: single-word-requests, psychology

Many forums have addressed this and none to my satisfaction. A narcissist loves their ideals, or something about themselves, just as a sociopath. Those who loathe their own existence do not always hate, more so they love others. It is our connection which pushes these poor souls away. A label may do no good, or exist, but it is truly an experience many endure.

Comment: Do you actually mean someone who is chronically depressed?

Comment: You're being unclear.  Do you mean someone who is simply "self-loathing", someone who is self-loathing because because they perceive that others loath them, or someone who is self-loathing because they feel it somehow benefits others to do so?

Comment: *Self-loathing, self-flagellating, self-torturing*....what's the context?